# Modify editability of a field from field group by code

Tags: axapta, x++

I have this piece of code:

```
controlDetails = this.form().design(1).addControl(FormControlType::Group, #quickCreateDetails);
    controlDetails.dataSource(fbds.id());
    controlDetails.dataGroup(#quickCreateDetails);
    controlDetails.frameType(10);
    controlDetails.autoDataGroup(true);
    controlDetails.hideIfEmpty(false);
    controlDetails.columns(2);
```

I want to modify the editability of one certain field on that dataGroup, but I don't know how to do it with code or in the AOT (DS). Seems like Im pretty much limited...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have next options:

1. change Form Data Source filed editability

   - via AOT - https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa860145.aspx
   - via code [FormDataSource.object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formdatasource.object.aspx): `InventTrans_ds.object(fieldNum(InventTrans, Qty)).allowEdit(false)`
2. change child control design property. `addControl` returns [`FormBuildGroupControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formbuildgroupcontrol.aspx). Then you have to loop through [*controlNum()*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formbuildgroupcontrol.controlnum.aspx), find correct design control and cast it to one of [FormBuildControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formbuildcontrol.aspx#familyToggle) nested type with data bounding. There you have [`allowEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formbuildgroupcontrol.allowedit.aspx) method.

Comment: Because I'm dynamically creating the form with parameters the second option seems the most practical for me, thanks.